# Python read csv, with four column

Tags: python, pandas

[Data from datadog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIW9D.png)

I am looking for some assistance reading this data from Datadog, I am reading it from the downloaded cvs. Wants to read in python so that create an application for the reading the same on regular intervals.

I have tried reading the data like below

`````py
import pandas as pd
fileload = pd.read_csv("DataSource/extract-2023-02-02T19_10_32.790Z.csv")
print(fileload)
fileload1 = pd.read_csv("DataSource/extract-2023-02-02T19_11_05.899Z.csv")
final = pd.concat([fileload, fileload1])
print(final)````


import csv

with open("DataSource/extract-2023-02-02T19_10_32.790Z.csv", 'r' ) as file:
    csvread = csv.reader(file)
    for i in file:
        print(i)
    a = pd.DataFrame([csvread])
    print(type(a))
`````

My expectation is that i can pick the last column with the all the data in the above format and further give column names to it. and then analyse data applying some aggregations on top.

Please assist

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
final[["final_column_name"]]
final['New_col_name'] = ...
```